# Subtitle won't wrap

Tags: lilypond

In my piece I have a long subtitle that runs off the sides of the page.

What I would really like is to manually add a `newline` or `carriage return`, or perhaps at least get `\wordwrap` to work.

I've followed the directions and examples in the docs for using `\wordwrap` - maybe I'm doing something wrong?

**Simple Sample Compilable Code**

```
\version "2.19.80"

\header {
    title = "Long Subtitle"
    subtitle = \markup \wordwrap { "THIS IS A TEST OF THE EMERGENCY BROADCAST SYSTEM.  REPEAT: THIS IS ONLY A TEST.  If this had been an actual emergency, the Attention Signal you just heard would have been followed by official information, news or instructions. " }
}

\score { <<  \new Staff  << \relative c''{  a b c d  } >>  >>  }
```

What it outputs (the gray indicates the edges of the paper):

[image: subtitle runs off the edges]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you could try the following:

```
subtitle = \markup {
    \column { 
        \wordwrap { 
            THIS IS A TEST OF THE EMERGENCY BROADCAST SYSTEM.  REPEAT: THIS IS ONLY A TEST.  If this had been an actual emergency, the Attention Signal you just heard would have been followed by official information, news or instructions.
        }
    }
}
```

Note the removal of the quotation marks and nesting `\markup`, `\column`, and `\wordwrap` within each other. You can read more about [Formatting Text](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.19/Documentation/notation/formatting-text) in the documentation.

Comment: I've spent at least 3 hours trying to figure this out.  I tried with and without quotes.  I never thought of putting brackets for wordwrap AND for markup, though.  It works without `column`, too.   Sometimes the docs don't seem to tell you what you want to find.   Thanks for taking the time.

Comment: In fact, if were writing all this in javascript, I wouldn't have any problem!  Javascript is more intuitive, I think.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the quotes.  That's all what is needed: `\wordwrap` expects individual words to wrap.  Alternatively, use `\wordwrap-string`.

The following works fine here:

```
\header {
  title = "Test"
  subtitle = \markup \wordwrap { 
THIS IS A TEST OF THE EMERGENCY BROADCAST SYSTEM.  REPEAT: THIS IS ONLY A TEST.  If this had been an actual emergency, the Attention Signal you just heard would have been followed by official information, news or instructions.
  }
}

\score { c'1 }
```

You state:

> I've followed the directions and examples in the docs for using \wordwrap - maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Obviously this cannot be the case here, so if you have suitable suggestions of how the documentation could be improved in order to keep others from making the same mistake, you'd likely want to forward them to the bug report list of LilyPond or at least discuss them on the user mailing list.

Comment: I know for a fact that I tried it that way and it errored out; but as I try it again now that way, it does work.  Maybe I was doing something else wrong, too.  And I object to `obviously this cannot be the case here` - my problem is trying to understand some of the syntax.  I can use quotes with `\markup \italic { }` but not with `\markup \wordwrap { }` - actually all of them compile without error, but if you use quotes with `\wordwarp` it just doesn't wrap.  It is difficult for me to grasp the syntax when it differs with commands (or so it seems to me).